# Change dropdown to searchbox from database (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

im still practicing at ajax and JS, so here's what im expecting
[image]

here's my current controller:

```
public function tambah()
{
    $this->data['namaProvinsi'] = $this->registrasi_model->get_nama_provinsi();
    $this->data['main_view'] = 'program/administrasi/registrasi_form';
    $this->data['form_action'] = site_url('program/administrasi/registrasi/tambah');

    if (! $_POST) {
        $registrasi = (object) $this->registrasi_model->default_value;
    } else {
        $registrasi = $this->input->post(null, true);
    }   

    if (! $this->registrasi_model->validate('form_rules')) {
        $this->data['values'] = (object) $registrasi;
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);
        return;
    }
}
```

model:

```
public function get_nama_provinsi()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT name FROM provinces ORDER BY name ASC');
    $dropdowns = $query->result();
    if(! $dropdowns){
        $finaldropdown[''] = " - Pilih - ";
        return $finaldropdown;
    }
    else{
        foreach ($dropdowns as $dropdown){
            $dropdownlist[$dropdown->name] = $dropdown->name;
        }
        $finaldropdown = $dropdownlist;
        $finaldropdown[''] = " - Pilih - ";
        return $finaldropdown;
    }
}
```

view:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm<?php set_validation_style('Provinsi')?>">        
    <?php echo form_label('Provinsi', 'provinsi', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-2')) ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <?php
            $atribut_prov = 'class="form-control"';
            $selectedProv = $this->registrasi_model->format_idPJTKI_namaPJTKI($values->ID_PJTKI);
            echo form_dropdown('Provinsi', $namaProvinsi, $selectedProv, $atribut_prov);
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (form_error('Provinsi')) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <?php echo form_error('Provinsi', '<span class="help-block">', '</span>');?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

i hope you understand my point here, i want to use textbox that if i type something it will show the closest value from the database.

i was trying to do json_encode on the controller function, but I don't know what to do next and im not sure if using json_encode to pass data from controller to js script is correct.

Comment: What I personnally do is that I put the database query in a separate file, and then use jQuery/AJAX to call this page after using `onkeydown` to record keystrokes in the field, if this makes sense.

Comment: Use Select2 js (https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html // try this

Comment: thanks i will try those

Answer (score 0):

thanks to aman, im using select2 for this case, and here's what i do:

adding this to view:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and changing

```
$atribut_prov = 'class="form-control"';
```

into

```
$atribut_Prov = 'class="form-control dropProv"';
echo form_dropdown('Provinsi', $namaProvinsi, $values->Provinsi, $atribut_Prov);
```

and lastly add this js:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropProv").select2({
                placeholder: "Pilih Provinsi"
            });
        });
 </script>
```